# Unable to run rodeo after pip installing

Tags: python, bash, pip, ipython

I am trying to run rodeo (http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/introducing-rodeo.html). I followed the instructions-- pip installed it. The install seemed to go fine, but when I type rodeo . , I get the following:

-bash: rodeo: command not found

The files from the install are stored in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rodeo (though I think it should be stored in /usr/bin/local) and there is no executable. Similar things happen when I try, for example, to pip install ipython. My guess is that it has something to do with my PATHs, but I have not been able to solve the problems. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see mention of a pip install of rodeo from the page you referenced. Rather, a .dmg file is downloaded, you should open it, and drag rodeo to your Applications folder. Start the rodeo app via the Applications folder. After starting, it checks your environment for other dependencies and asks your approval for installation. Install all the missing pieces, apparently one at a time, since you keep clicking "TRY STARTING AGAIN" after each install.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing on my ubuntu PC. And 'rodeo' command didn't work too.

So, What i did is

1. search where the rodeo app was installed
2. rodeo app was installed in '/opt/Rodeo/' path. (If you installed in other path, then revise beneath command)
3. type command '/opt/Rodeo/rodeo' and punch the enter button.

   - I don't know why but, where your set directory in terminal window,
     It is not allowed to omit 'opt/Rodeo/'.

I hope it works on your computer.